# What is the best tool to measure latitude the most accurately?

Tags: land-survey, latitude-longitude

What is the best tool to measure latitude the most accurately? I'm thinking it's the sextant but not sure. I tried looking it up on Google and came across this site but have found nothing useful. I am doing this for a research paper and need help.

Comment: Hi Lucy, welcome to the site! Could you edit your question to include more detail? At the moment, it might seem a bit like a joke to many people on this site, since a sextant is nowadays only used in very specific situations (mainly as a backup in marine navigation), and it's certainly not the most precise tool to measure latitude. What kind of research paper are you writing, and what context of measuring latitude are you thinking about?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome Lucy -- your question is a little bit unusual for this site, which mainly caters to people who use geographic information systems professionally or in research.

I found it surprisingly hard to google up a site that has a concise history and comparison of navigation tools over time. However, I think the [Smithsonian Museum's Time and Navigation site](http://timeandnavigation.si.edu/navigating-at-sea/longitude-problem/observing-the-skies) does a great job. If you start on the page I linked, and then explore the modern options (to the right), you should get an overview, including on the more accurate options compared to the somewhat outdated sextant.